# how to choose random datetime of two different columns?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, slice

After some merging data, I have got a `dataframe` as:

```
Name      Stage           Start                 End

Hulk        A1     21/10/2018 06:34:15    21/10/2018 07:34:15
Hulk        A4     21/10/2018 07:34:15    21/10/2018 08:34:15
Sam         A1     21/10/2018 09:34:15    21/10/2018 10:34:15
Sam         A4     21/10/2018 10:34:15    21/10/2018 11:34:15
```

so I need to arrange these data as follows, in form like `start` of `A1` and `end` of `A4`:

```
Name      Stage           Start                 End

Hulk        A1,A4     21/10/2018 06:34:15    21/10/2018 08:34:15
Sam         A1,A4     21/10/2018 09:34:15    21/10/2018 11:34:15
```

How this could be acheived ? I am quite new with `python` and `pandas`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) what working with [`first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html) and [`last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) function nice, if for each group are 2 Stage values ordered like in sample data:

Also [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=join#str.join) is pure python function.

```
df = df.groupby('Name', as_index=False).agg({'Stage':', '.join,'Start':'first', 'End':'last'})
print (df)
   Name   Stage                Start                  End
0  Hulk  A1, A4  21/10/2018 06:34:15  21/10/2018 08:34:15
1   Sam  A1, A4  21/10/2018 09:34:15  21/10/2018 11:34:15
```

Comment: thanks for the solution.

But in doc of `agg` under `pandas` there is no info about `join` , `first` , `last`...How do one learn about it ? @jezrael